# How to return GitHub api in laravel blade

Tags: laravel

IF you visit github api for any user `https://api.github.com/users/{USERNAME}/repos` you'll find all repositories of that user listed there, now I want to loop this repositories in my blade but I can't.

I tried simple url as I shared above, as well with `json_decode` but no luck.

[image: one]

**Any idea how to loop such data?**

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: @ali the code is the url i mentioned and the form of data that the url returns is in the image i shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I am using this code and now working with no issue

```
// We make the actuall curl initialization
$ch = curl_init(MY_REPOS_API_URL);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// We set the right headers: any user agent type, and then the custom token header part that we generated
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: Awesome-Octocat-App'));

// We execute the curl
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// And we make sure we close the curl
curl_close($ch);

// Then we decode the output and we could do whatever we want with it
$output = json_decode($output);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567582/8490993)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Guzzle to call the API (I can't comment for clarity), you can get the results of the call like so (where $response is the value of your call):

```
$response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

Then pass to the view:

```
return view('view')->with(compact('response'));
```

Then loop with blade:

```
   @foreach ($response as $results)
     // do something
   @endforeach
```

If an object isn't what you're wanting to work with, you can convert those results to an array by passing a second parameter of `true` to the `json_decode()` function

Hope that helps but let me know if not :)

If you don't have Guzzle in your application:

1 - Pull the dependancy into your application with Composer

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

2 - Instantiate Guzzle in the controller which will call the Github API and make the `GET` request:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/{USERNAME}/repos');
```

3 - Access the results:

```
$response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

Info taken from Guzzle Docs:
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: thanks man but none of `getBody` or `getContents` nor together as you wrote can't get any data they just return errors. `Call to a member function getBody() on string`

Comment: When you call the URL in a browser, you are doing a `GET` request on the URL. Like the following link returns all info to do with my user - https://api.github.com/users/shane-chris-barker/repos. What you need to do is make that call with PHP. It can be achieved using Curl (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or Guzzle (http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/). Once you are able to make a `GET` request to the URL, you'll be able to pass these to your view :)

Comment: Updated the answer to show to install Guzzle into your application :)

Comment: @mafortis no probs - I see you went for CURL :) If you're going to be doing lots of stuff with PHP and API's, I'd deffo get into Guzzle and how it works :)